# what do these swing color names mean

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, uimanager

Some of the names are clear, like background, foreground, focus etc. But some are just confusing, like light, hightlight, shadow, darkshardow etc. I noticed that these are consistently used in swing UI, so I infer these are part of java's jargon.  Does any body know if there is a document out there that explains these names ?

```
RadioButton.background  
RadioButton.darkShadow  
RadioButton.disabledText    
RadioButton.focus           
RadioButton.foreground  
RadioButton.highlight   
RadioButton.light           
RadioButton.select          
RadioButton.shadow
```

Comment: Why not individually change them to something like pink and see what happens?

Comment: I have been trying that for weeks now, nothing seems to get affected, especially with light, highlight :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are `UIResource` elements related to `JRadionButton`. Each `Look & Feel` provides different radio button appearance, and may set different defaults for these elements. It is also to up to L&F implementation to use these keys or not.

For example, here is a method from `javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicBorders` that uses `RadioButton.light` and `RadioButton.highlight`:

```
public static Border getRadioButtonBorder() {
UIDefaults table = UIManager.getLookAndFeelDefaults();
Border radioButtonBorder = new BorderUIResource.CompoundBorderUIResource(
           new BasicBorders.RadioButtonBorder(
                   table.getColor("RadioButton.shadow"),
                                       table.getColor("RadioButton.darkShadow"),
                                       table.getColor("RadioButton.light"),
                                       table.getColor("RadioButton.highlight")),
                     new MarginBorder());
return radioButtonBorder;
}
```

However, it is may not be used by concrete L&F implementations.

PS: 
[UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) by @camickr can be handy to visualize different keys.